# How much stronger does gravity have to be for space travel to be impossible?

Tags: rockets, gravity

I’ve heard that only a slightly stronger gravitational pull would make it impossible for rockets to launch. Is this true? I’ve heard this used as the reason why humanity is meant to be in space.

Comment: This is a really interesting topic, *Welcome to Space!* It might **or might not** eventually be closed as a duplicate of [How much bigger could Earth be, before rockets would't work?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14383/12102) but that doesn't mean that its not an excellent question. [Astronaut Don Pettit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donald_Pettit)'s blog post [The Tyranny of the Rocket Equation](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/expeditions/expedition30/tryanny.html) is worth a read, despite its mipselled url.

Comment: Humanity isn't meant to be in space because under different circumstances it wouldn't be able to get there?  I'm not meant to go to the swimming pool because if it was full of burning petrol I'd die!

Comment: @DaveGremlin you read that backwards.

Comment: I bet a completely water covered planet would have a hard time launching rockets to space.

Comment: @Criggie Sea launch of rockets has been done. *Constructing* them, of course, would be challenging.

Comment: You face the problem from the wrong side ... a slightly stronger gravitational force will maybe not prevent space flight - it most likely will prevent creation of planets / make those planets orbit too close around HOTTER, short-lived stars which would prevent life as we know it (because evolution won't have enough time) - and in turn make space flight impossible

Comment: @eagle275: I expect the OP is asking about whether life on larger planets (i.e., those with higher surface gravity) would be trapped there, rather than if the constant *g* was different.  Fair point regarding star formation, though.

Comment: While some people are obviously considering this a dupe of the rocket's-won't-work question it is not because non-rocket answers meet the requirements.

Comment: @JonofAllTrades Exactly. Me and a friend had this thought experiment that if space flight was so determined by gravity then even if there were other advanced civilizations out there, they would likely be confined to their planet. This would mean aliens are extremely unlikely to find us because not only are you against the probability of life, are also against the probability of having a higher gravitational pull.

Answer (score 61):

There's no "bright line" at which space travel would become impossible; a slightly stronger gravitational pull would require bigger and more expensive rockets. Linear increases in gravity require *exponential* increases in the size and expense of the rocket, so at some point it becomes impractical<sup>1</sup>. At some point there's a theoretical barrier (no material exists that you can build a rocket of the required size out of, for example) but the practical engineering and resource limits kick in much earlier than that.

For a planet with twice the surface gravity of Earth, for example, [you need a rocket about 90 times the mass of the Atlas launchers used for Project Mercury](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17460/195) just to get one person into low planetary orbit. That's 4 times the mass of the Saturn V; beyond that point I don't think most civilizations would even try it.

> I’ve heard this used as the reason why humanity is meant to be in space.

Humanity isn't meant to do anything except what humanity decides to do.

<sup>1</sup> This may seem intuitively strange, but consider that the more fuel you add, the heavier the rocket is, and so adding 50% more total thrust involves adding much more than 50% more fuel (and thus overall rocket size). This is already a significant mass penalty under Earth gravity, so increases in gravity would make this issue more glaring. For more, read about the [Tsiolkovsky Rocket Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation).

Comment: Ah so a linear increase in gravity causes an exponential increase in costs. I guess it’s an economic question over a physical one.

Comment: @ImranQ while RB doesn't link to their [answer here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/17576/12102), it's really worth reading, and it graphically demonstrates that exponential behavior. [This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26866/12102) also links to some further scientific work on the topic.

Comment: @ImranQ: What does economics has anything to do with it?

Comment: The exponential part comes from that you have to at any given time lift the weight of the fuel you need for the rest of the trip.

Comment: @EricDuminil Sire, the peasants are revolting. || "Yes. Aren't they". || The Apollo program cost $US0.50/day for every US citizen throughout. When you need Saturn Vs to orbit John Glen the peasants are liable to revolt when you try to put men (or women) on the Moon.

Comment: In a very nerdy sense, there is a very hard limit.  For a spherical, nonrotating object of radius $R$, then if the mass of the object $M\ge c^2R/(2G)$ then the object is inside its Schwarzchild radius and there are no possible paths any kind of rocket can take out.

Comment: @EricDuminil Almost everything.

Comment: @J... It's not quadratic; you don't need a Saturn V to get a single person into Earth orbit. We did it with the [120-ton Atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_LV-3B), about 1/25 the size of the Saturn V. Also, I'm pretty sure you can't definitively tell if a relationship is quadratic or exponential from just two data points. I'll edit to clarify that the 2x and 4x aren't directly related.

Comment: @RussellBorogove: Yup.  The Saturn V carried a massively bigger payload to a much higher orbit.  I think there would be a practical engineering limit as increasing the amount of fuel would require commensurate increases to the mass of the engines and structure, to the point that they would become an increasing fraction of the ship's overall mass.  Staging would typically help, but again only to a point, because while adding stages reduces the amount of mass that needs to be accelerated later in the missions, the staging hardware itself has mass.

Comment: @supercat Yeah, I think my extrapolations up to 2g surface are reasonable, but my other answer with extrapolations beyond that aren't valid.

Comment: @RussellBorogove My bad - in my mind you were talking about the same mission, I misread.  In any case, I like your edit - the comparison is more evident now.  The difference between one person to LEO vs a 3-crew return mission to the moon with lander isn't really intuitive, so a 2 -> 4x comparison doesn't really capture the scale of the difference.  The Atlas example is much better!

Comment: @RussellBorogove: I too like the way the edit mentions the size ratio in comparison to both a craft with a comparable mission and to a larger-mission rocket that's at the upper limits of practicality.

Comment: The mention of cost/expense seems odd in the sense that we know the Earth's gravity will not significantly change (nor will Earthlings be on other habitable worlds anytime soon) so we're probably talking about hypothetical civilizations on hypothetical worlds.  Why assume an alien civilization will even _have_ money, let alone a currency system that scales linearly like ours does? Perhaps they use a logarithmic currency such that a doubling in expense gets you 10 times the buying power. Better to stick with the physical aspects, imo.

Comment: @aroth Why assume the cost/expense is in terms of money? Building and launching a rocket costs metal and labour and fuel. There is no alternate economy where twice as much metal makes ten times as many rockets (of the same size).

Comment: @tfb By that point life on that 'planet' would be quite interesting (if at all possible) as well. Do you have a limit for rotating bodies too?

Comment: @Mast: you'd need to look at the Kerr metric which is more complicated, especially if the spin is large.  Note that for Earth to be inside its own Schwarzschild radius the mass would have to increase by a factor of nearly $10^9$: it would have to have about $2000$ times the mass of the entire Solar system.  Like I said, a nerdy limit.

Comment: @tfb Yes, I understood we're talking (nearly) black-hole masses here.

Answer (score 17):

As [this article](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14383/12102) points out, rockets quickly get impractical.  For example, at 10 times earth gravity, the rocket's mass is comparable to the planet's mass, so that's definitely some sort of limit!

But who said we have to use rockets?  Suppose we build a monorail completely encircling the planet at some convenient height $h$ above the ground, and accelerate a vehicle until it's actually in orbit at height $h$ (plus a tiny bit).  Then we can use this as a launch platform.  Once we're in orbit, albeit at a ludicrously low height, we can use that to maneuver into a higher orbit without using vast amounts of fuel.  I mean, this neglects air resistance, and the danger to the rest of the population is of XKCD-like proportions, but on the right planet ...

Comment: You think of a space elevator.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen The lat/long of space elevator cargo presumably remains fixed while it gains altitude. It doesn't achieve orbital velocity until it reaches geosync altitude (or hops off and achieves the necessary delta-v in another way). The "launch train" Adam describes is like the dual of the space elevator: it focuses on achieving orbital velocity first, and then increasing altitude.

Comment: So rockets are impractical, and a globe-girdling hypersonic monorail is not?

Comment: @Organic Marble a globe-girdling hypersonic monorail is a bit less impractical than a planetary mass rocket yes.

Comment: It's xkcd's orbit explanation anyway (orbits aren't very high -- they are just very fast).

Comment: There is no material which could withstand the heat from going that fast in an atmosphere (there isn't even on earth with 0.1 that mass). So you would have to build a vacuum tube (yeah, that's on the same level of impracticality, so it's doable); but *then* you couldn't leave that tube, so you'd need to build a branch that's as high as the atmosphere... under much higher gravity... I think it's theoretically impossible.

Comment: XKCD poses a threat comparable to a craft travelling at orbital velocity? Someone ought to do something about the guy!

Comment: "I mean, this neglects air resistance" - ...which is likely significant at 10x Earth gravity.  You could possibly make it a hyperloop instead of a monorail, but would still need some sort of "launch shunt" to an altitude above the edge of (most of) the atmosphere if you don't want your launch vehicles to experience significant deceleration and likely disintegration the instant they hit the air outside of the hyperloop.

Comment: @OrganicMarble: With an increase in gravity, the practicality of "free flying" (i.e. rockets avoiding drag, as opposed to planes which seek it) dramatically decreases, whereas the practicality of the monorail does not decrease as much (proportionally speaking). In absence of reasonably achievable free flight (i.e. rockets), the monorail would be considered (by this high-gravity-civilization) to be more feasible way to attempt the first spaceflight (compared to our civilization).

Comment: The convenient thing is that as gravity increases, so does the atmospheric pressure gradient, which means you don't need to go as high up (maybe 25 miles instead of 60 for a maglev-type monorail).

Comment: @aroth, due to the increased gravity, wouldn't the height to get out of the atmosphere be considerably less? Or at least get to an altitude where the drag would be negligible? Also, wouldn't aerodynamics be considerably better, so that could be incorporated as well? I'm sure these are only part of the answer as well, since there's probably 1000 different variables that need to be considered, as well as "thinking outside the box" to a completely different style of locomotion.

Comment: I'm not sure that follows. If we take Uranus as an example (next largest planet in the solar system from Earth), its troposphere extends to a height of 50km.  On Earth the troposphere has a height of 12km. But then Venus has a taller troposphere than both, despite being slightly less massive than Earth.  So it seems like the total mass of the atmosphere on the planet is a bigger factory than gravity.  Put the Earth's atmosphere under 2G, and it'll get shorter. But if the more massive planet also has a more massive atmosphere (which you'd tend to expect?) then all bets are off.

Answer (score 8):

A (very high) upper limit is defined by the thrust to weight ratio of the first stage engine itself. The engine without a tank and a payload would not be able to lift off if the thrust is smaller than its weight measured under the high gravity.

An engine build for such an extreme gravity would need more structal weight than at Earth's gravity. The atmospheric pressure of a planet with extreme gravity would be very high and reduce the engines exhaust velocity and thrust.

If we define the ratio of engine mass, structural mass, fuel mass and payload mass as well as engine thrust for a hypothetical first stage, we may calculate the maximum gravity for this stage to take off. Payload mass of the first stage would be all other stages total mass plus the spaceship.

Comment: Probably the soundest answer from the standpoint of actual engineering.

Comment: How much does height affect the equation? For example, if Mt. Everest were near the equator, would that trivially or significantly reduce the first stage thrust requirements? Similarly, how much would an airplane or balloon launch affect the equation?

Comment: @TracyCramer Very high mountains can't exist on planets with high gravity. Rocks under very high pressure will flow slowly.

Answer (score 4):

Note that you seem to be assuming chemical propulsion. Nuclear propulsion would work against even stronger gravity, but there are major safety problems.

Comment: Can you back up your assertion that "nuclear propulsion would work" with any references? A nuclear propelled booster has never "worked" on Earth, only been studied.

Comment: Adding to that comment, nuclear thermal engines have been ground-tested to work but currently have somewhat low TWR: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40692/why-do-nuclear-rockets-e-g-nerva-have-such-poor-thrust-to-weight-ratios

Comment: As @lirtosiast mentions, nuclear thermal engines have poor thrust to weight ratios.  If you don't care about the planet you're launching from there are high thrust to weight nuclear engines that are plausible, Zubrin's [Nuclear Salt Water Rocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_salt-water_rocket) is particularly amusing.

Comment: @Aethernaught Haha, _"Writing the environmental impact statement for such tests [...] might present an interesting problem ..."_

Comment: I guess you could scale [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)) to higher gravity easier than chemical rockets.

Comment: I think there is little doubt that atomic explosion powered propulsion could overcome almost any amount of gravity. If you actually look at the plans for Project Orion, it was to propel incredibly huge objects into space, unimaginably large for a chemical rocket. The thrust-to-weight ratio for an atomic explosion is... very large. This should be in the answer as well as a reference to Project Orion. Also very low radioactive atomic explosions can (and to an extent have been) engineered.

Comment: @MikeWise Actually, there's a bit of question about Orion for planetary takeoff--keeping the pusher plate from melting.  It's sitting there not that far away from nuclear-powered fireballs, it's going to collect a lot of thermal energy.

Comment: Talked about in the "Potential Problems" section on Wikipedia. They didn't seem to think that was much of a problem. But I imagine there are a lot of unknown challenges. Still, if a lot of very good engineers and physicists thought it was feasible in the late 40's, I would think that now, 70-80 years later we have a lot more material options and almost an infinity more ability to simulate and thus design appropriate fission "bombs" for propulsion than they did. Maybe not as many experienced bomb designers though :)

Answer (score 1):

Gravity will not keep a species out of space, although it can make it incredibly expensive.  A resource-limited species might not be able to make it to space, though--I'm thinking of Jovians.

Chemical rockets suffer the tyranny of the rocket equation, if you need more than 30km/sec to attain orbit I don't think you're doing it, period.  However, that's not the only way to space.

user6030 brought up nuclear rockets--nuclear thermal doesn't have the thrust but nuclear pulse (aka Project Orion) does, although there is some question if the pusher plate can be kept from melting.  (Before it got scrapped by the atmospheric test ban treaty it got as far as confirming the basic idea--you can use a nearby nuclear detonation for propulsion and survive.  What is not answered is if you can keep the plate cool enough in the face of repeated detonations.)  Using fusion bombs you can get an ISP of nearly 8,000 -- nearly 20x what you can get from chemical rockets and thus letting you lift off from a world with an escape velocity of perhaps 1000 km/sec.

However, there are three other approaches I'm aware of that have no limits whatsoever other than you must be in a world with chemistry (they might not suffice to get you off a neutron star) in order to build them.  All are megaengineering on a scale beyond anything the human race has done to date.

First, and easiest, the launch loop.  Build two stations, they lob iron bars back and forth.  You need some ginormous magnets to turn them around but no super materials.  You build an evacuated tunnel for them, then start flinging them faster and faster--above orbital velocity.  Your tunnel is basically a maglev track upside-down--instead of the train riding the track the track rides the train of flying bars.  Lift enough of the track out of the atmosphere, then put another linear motor on top to launch from.

Second, the space fountain.  Same basic idea but you have only one station, it throws the bars straight up and you have a series of platforms that extract energy from the bars heading up and transfer it to the ones going back down.  You have to build to synchronous altitude, then just push off and you're in orbit.

Finally, my own design.  Adam Chalcraft sort of touched on it but his is nowhere near a complete solution.  Build an evacuated tunnel around the world, supported on pillars.  Once again, pieces (or perhaps a solid object in this case) moving at above orbital velocity, riding a track on the top of the tunnel.  Spin this until the outward force matches the weight of the tunnel and it's pillars--the net downward force should be zero.  Now, do it again on top of the first one.  Unlike a building where each floor must be able to support all the floors above, in this case each layer is supported by the spinning weight.  The bottom ones have no greater load than the top ones.  Repeat until you're out of the atmosphere, then you can launch with a linear motor.

(A simple proof this works:  Take it to the infinite extreme--an infinite number of pillars and zero space between the rings.  While it can't actually be built that way it should be obvious the forces involved go to zero in this case.  Thus the only question is how close together do they need to be given the limits of the construction materials.)

Answer (score 0):

In Russell Borogove's answer, they assert "Linear increases in gravity require exponential increases in the size and expense of the rocket, so at some point it becomes impractical." That is the physics answer, but it's slightly different from an economics perspective. A more precise statement would be that if the only variables are payload and gravity, then payload decreases exponentially with gravity. But they are not the only variables. As the cost grows, there is more and more pressure to decrease the cost. There are many places where more cost-effectiveness could be squeezed out. The US continues to launch from Cape Canaveral, despite equitorial launch sites being optimal. Research into nuclear power has been stymied by safety concerns. And so on. This is very much the realm of unknown unknowns, but it's very likely that a civilization on a planet with gravity significantly greater than Earth's could, if properly motivated, engage in space travel.

Answer (score -2):

If gravity is higher, the density of the atmosphere would be higher as well, and probably also to a greater altitude as well as less would have evaporated into space.  So hydrogen or helium balloons would rise up more rapidly or lift more weight to possibly higher altitudes.  Maybe this would be the main way of accessing space travel on this imaginary planet.

Comment: Do balloons really work better on planets with higher gravity?

Comment: Balloons operate on the principle of buoyancy, which is based purely on density. A buoyant object in a fluid will rise to the level at which it displaces the same *weight* of fluid as itself.  Since increased gravity also increases the weight of such payloads by the same proportion, it follows that balloons would give even *less* altitude gain, for the observed reason of a shallower altitude.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan The answer clearly states *density* as justification. Yes, increased weight from higher *g* cancels out, but if there is more total *mass* per volume due to higher *g*, then balloons would be more effective.

Comment: @LawnmowerMan: The weight of the payload is increased, but so is the mass of the displaced atmosphere. And both are increased by the same factor. However, the key here is density. The lift from a balloon is caused by the lifting gas weighing *less* then the atmosphere. That means you still have the same ration of lifting gas mass and lifted mass, but the increased density means a smaller volume. As a result, the balloon itself (the fabric) can be smaller and lighter, leaving a higher payload mass.

Comment: @MSalters That's an interesting point. Let's explore it a bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_air_balloon#Envelope. Using a hot air balloon as a starting point, we see a typical small balloon has a 250 lb. envelope, 150 lb. basket, and 1200 lbs. of "payload". Since the envelope is already less than 25% of total non-gas mass, you can't get more than a 33% payload improvement from this. Since surface area increases slower than volume, this will cause the envelope to be an even smaller proportion at scale.

Comment: Space isn't high, space is fast.  The main thing that determines how much "fast" you need is the planet's surface gravity.  The atmosphere is nearly irrelevant.